# python: Overhead to using classes instead of dictionaries?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

First, I'd like to point out that I know OOP concepts and understand the differences between dictionaries and classes. My question is about what makes sense design wise in this case:

I am designing a webapp in python and I have to represent something like a book object.
Books have chapters and chapters have titles and content. For simplicity, lets say that the content is plain text.

My question is, should I make the book and chapter classes or dictionaries? I know it'd look neater to use book.chapter instead of book['chapter'], and if I end up having methods in the future, it might make sense to puts them in the book class. However, I'd like to know if there is any overhead to using classes instead of storing the information in dictionaries?

If I don't want to instantiate a book object from a database everytime and store it as a pickle, I'd have to be worried about incompatibility with past book objects if I add/remove data members from a class.I feel that it'd be easier to deal with this problem in dictionaries. Any pointers on whether/when it makes sense to use dictionaries instead of classes?

Answer (score 10):

This is *highly* unlikely to be the bottleneck in your application, so worrying about the performance is probably a waste of time. However, if this is the bottleneck or you just have some time on your hands, look into using a [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields). It combines the immutability and low memory footprint of a `tuple` with the nice syntax of class attributes.

Comment: +1 for mentioning namedtuple.  If you're using Python >= 2.6, it's definitely a good choice to look into.

Comment: +1: It's not "probably a waste of time".  It's a waste of time.  All the web frameworks use classes.  Just use classes.

Comment: S. Lott, what does "All the web frameworks use classes" have to do with this?  Are you suggesting the web frameworks are guides for best bare-metal performance?  Or are you suggesting, they're "fast enough", even with the (very small) overhead of classes.

Answer (score 8):

A few thoughts:

1. If you start with a dictionary, you can always switch to a custom class later that implements the mapping protocol (or subclasses dict).  So it's probably a good starting point.
2. You can define custom Python objects to use `__slots__`, which will be faster and more memory efficient if you have a large number of objects.
3. If you use a custom Python object, it will be easier to replace it in the future with an object written in C.  (I've never tried it, but I would expect that subclassing dict from C would be a tricky proposition.)

Answer (score 5):

You actually summarize the trade-offs quite well. It seems lots of people get worried far too early about performance. Rather than repeat the standard advice on the subject I'll suggest you search the web for "Knuth premature optimization". The fact of the matter is that for objects of *known structure* you will be very much happier using class-based objects than dicts.

Again, your desire not to instantiate objects each time their (instance) data is read in form the database represents a slightly unhealthy focus on the wrong parts of your program's design. Creating an instance of one of your classes from data attributes takes very little time, and the convenience of being able to add behavior through methods is well worth the slight extra complexity.

Using a dict with constant subscripts to reference the elements of a data object seems wrong-headed to me. You are effectively emulating Python's namespace mechanism and creating lots of unnecessary string constants (which won't necessarily be consolidated by the interpreter). If you're really interested in speed then why not use a list, with symbolic constants for the field names? Answer: because it would be wrong-headed to contort your code  in this way for a potentially illusory increase in execution speed that in 99% of all cases (a figure I just plucked from my ass) isn't going to be noticed because the application isn't CPU-bound anyway.

Write your program the easiest way you know how. If it works and runs fast enough, move on to the next task.

Answer (score 4):

Objects were originally created to bundle data with functionality. If you just want to store data, use dictionaries. If you want to include methods for manipulating the data, use objects.

Comment: I think the first sentence is a myth.

Comment: @Svante, If it is a myth, then what is the truth?

Comment: No, I read it in a C book that traced the history of data types.

Comment: @Svante: Disagree: the object model is designed to couple attributes and behavior.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Fundamental_concepts

Comment: OK, I guess I took the word "bundle" too serious.  "couple" is much better.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of similar to your problem: [Returning an object vs returning a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794132/returning-an-object-vs-returning-a-tuple)

There's no clearcut choice. Dictionaries are fast, nice, and clean. Class instances are, after all, a special dictionary. If you want to provide a way to add functionalities and change your interface later on, a class would be the best choice, but overdesign something simple is always a bad choice. Python is not java, where everything must be an instance of a properly made class. This is a sin I fall for as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you go with objects, I wouldn't store the data pickled in the database simply for the reasons you gave. It would be considerably worse if you underwent a change of language or similar.

FWIW, I would start with a dictionary. If things get complicated or new features are needed, make it an object.

Comment: Raw dicts are much easier to dump to JSON, exchange with other programs and the like.  They require no custom class definitions (other than a description of the nesting convention, which here is obvious).